# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions - how to fix this CI error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, internationalization

Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions, I need help on fixing this. Thanks

```js
export const setDecimalFormat = amount => {
  ['de' , 'fr'].includes(getLocale())
    ? amount.replace(/\./g, ',')
    : amount;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning the value

> If an arrow function is simply returning a single line of code, you
>   can omit the statement brackets and the return keyword. This tells the
>   arrow function to return the statement.

```
export const setDecimalFormat = amount => {
  return ['de' , 'fr'].includes(getLocale())
    ? amount.replace(/\./g, ',')
    : amount;
};
```

Comment: I forgot to upvote and thank you sir, but this really helped me.